# HTML display tables in one line with scrollbar in X asys

Tags: html, css

I need to display list of tables (atm tables is ul list) and if there is no enough space in wrapper - scrollbar on asys X should appear. I know this is pure css but I can't find out why elements are moving to bottom if them not fits..

What I have now:

```
    .blocks_wrapper .categories_table_wrapper{
    margin-top: 14px;
    width: 954px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding: 0;
    height: 211px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}
.blocks_wrapper .categories_table_wrapper .categories_table{
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 18px;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 192px;
    max-height: 192px;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.blocks_wrapper .categories_table_wrapper .categories_table li{
    width: 100%;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #757575;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 40px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    position: relative;
}
.blocks_wrapper .categories_table_wrapper .categories_table li:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 9px;
    height: 24px;
    background-image: url('../images/icons/cat_ticker.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    top: 0;
    right: 10px;
}
.blocks_wrapper .categories_table_wrapper .categories_table li:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
.categories_table_wrapper .categories_table li.active, .categories_table_wrapper .categories_table li:hover{ background-color: #ffffff!important; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tp1qsg54/ 
and as you can see there is 3 tables on the wrapper and the third one should be next to second one in the same line but now it is at the bottom (after second)... How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `ul` elements are set as `inline-block`, and inline-block/inline elements respect whitespaces including line breaks. So in your case, three tables don't fit in the row due to additional whitespaces width.

Simple fix is to set font size to `0` on the parent container so that whitespaces effectively get rendered as zero-sized. just don't forget to reset font size to proper value on the table level afterwards:

```css
.blocks_wrapper .categories_table_wrapper{
    /* ... */
    font-size: 0; /* <--- this line does the trick */
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/tp1qsg54/1/

Comment: Thanks for help, but look http://jsfiddle.net/tp1qsg54/2/ - only three tables fits in one line. It should be fine with N tables in container..

Comment: yes, like that :) but it works in jsfiddle and doesn't work at my page. Could it be bootstrap problems? Becouse design is compared with bootstrap.

Comment: I've used the same css code of jsfiddle ant the result is http://prntscr.com/7d8g2i

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. After removing left floating, everything started working. Thanks!